# Docker Container running error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, swarm

I am using  Fedora 26 Os and Docker Version is (docker-ce-18.03.0.ce).

Whenever i am using new docker container i am getting below mentioned error

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

[image: Error message]

Comment: which error? Show your command + error

Comment: Please dont't add your error message as image. Use code styling instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

```
docker image ls
```

and make sure the image with the name swarm is there